How can I get files from a page comments in Notion via API?
I am trying to extract comments via the Notion API. I have used the endpoints https://api.notion.com/v1/comments?block_id=<BLOCK_ID> and https://api.notion.com/v1/comments/<COMMENT_ID>. I can retrieve all rich text information but not files. How can I obtain files (such as images and videos) from comments?
PS: I can retrieve images from page blocks, but not for comments..."

Here is the answer of the Notion's support team:

Unfortunately, Notion API does not supports retrieving images and videos from page comments.

